# How to show instructions to user while using Ionic mobile app?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid

How to show instructions to user while using `Ionic mobile app?`

I am not asking about introduction `sliders`, After successful login user don't know how to use some apps. So, I want to give some instructions to  user.

**Please help me.**

Comment: You are looking something like this https://i.pinimg.com/236x/4d/ce/18/4dce18b45fc7793fbce23592e4b92eb6--salesforce-american-express.jpg

Comment: Exactly. You got my point Thank you for that, Do you have any solution for this please help me if you know.